# Move files with a set speed

Tags: java, file, move

I am developing a program which scans some folders in the background and moves some files on certain events. My problem with this is, that i don't want to completely block the drive(s) i am currently working on, so my questions are:
Is there a way to restrict file move speed?
If not, would using input/output streams to copy files and putting Thread.sleep after each call achieve my goal?

I am at the moment using mp3agic to save the files to another location and delete the originals afterwards, but i want to look into an own implementation of a file move method.

Here is the current code:

```
public void save(String newFilename) throws IOException, NotSupportedException {
    if (path.toAbsolutePath().compareTo(Paths.get(newFilename).toAbsolutePath()) == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Save filename same as source filename");
    }
    try (SeekableByteChannel saveFile = Files.newByteChannel(Paths.get(newFilename), EnumSet.of(StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.WRITE))) {
        if (hasId3v2Tag()) {
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(id3v2Tag.toBytes());
            byteBuffer.rewind();
            saveFile.write(byteBuffer);
        }
        saveMpegFrames(saveFile);
        if (hasCustomTag()) {
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(customTag);
            byteBuffer.rewind();
            saveFile.write(byteBuffer);
        }
        if (hasId3v1Tag()) {
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(id3v1Tag.toBytes());
            byteBuffer.rewind();
            saveFile.write(byteBuffer);
        }
        saveFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: share some code snippet please

Comment: 1.) how is your actual implementation of the move operation? 2.) yes you could use in/out streams in conjunction with some kind of sleep/wait to ensure that you only write a certain amount of bytes per sec (read -> sleep -> write -> repeat).

Comment: Sorry, updated the post with the source code